# Inserting levels for paragraph and sub paragraph using Java

Tags: java

I would like to have a way to achieve marking the levels as Para, Sub-Para and Clause, given below is the input and output format of the text

Input Text:

```
 (A) Preparations 
 (1) Required ingredients to prepare...
 (a) 100ml of coconut oil
 (b) 2 table spoon of lemon mixed..
 (B) Process steps
 (i) Mix well the ...
 (ii) Apply in all parts of ...
 (iii) Gently give a massage..
```

Output Text:

```
 <Level type="Para" id="(A)">
      (A) Preparations 
      <Level type="Sub-Para" id="(A)(1)">
           (1) Required ingredients to prepare...
           <Level type="Clause" id="(A)(1)(a)">
                (a) 100ml of coconut oil
           <Level type="Clause" id="(A)(1)(b)">
                (b) 2 table spoon of lemon mixed..
 <Level type="Para" id="(B)">
      (B) Process steps
      <Level type="Sub-Para" id="(B)(i)">
           (i) Mix well the ...
      <Level type="Sub-Para" id="(B)(ii)">
           (ii) Apply in all parts of ...
      <Level type="Sub-Para" id="(B)(iii)">
           (iii) Gently give a massage..
```

Please assist how this can be achieved using Java. I will try on my own.

The text alignment is shown just for better understanding the levels.

If I'm not clear in explaining the question please let me know, I will modify the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class App2 {


private static final String PARA_STRING = "<Level type=\"Para\" id=\"%s\">\n\t%s";
private static final String SUBPARA_STRING = "\t<Level type=\"Sub-Para\" id=\"%s%s\">\n\t\t%s";
private static final String CLAUSE_STRING = "\t\t<Level type=\"Clause\" id=\"%s%s%s\">\n\t\t\t%s";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
    input.append("(A) Preparations");
    input.append("\n");
    input.append("(1) Required ingredients to prepare...");
    input.append("\n");
    input.append("(a) 100ml of coconut oil");
    input.append("\n");
    input.append("(b) 2 table spoon of lemon mixed..");
    input.append("\n");
    input.append("(B) Process steps");
    input.append("\n");
    input.append("(i) Mix well the ...");
    input.append("\n");
    input.append("(ii) Apply in all parts of ...");
    input.append("\n");
    input.append("(iii) Gently give a massage..");
    input.append("\n");

    buildParagraphs(input.toString());
}

/**
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void buildParagraphs(String input) throws Exception
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    String[] inputArray = input.split("\n");
    String paraPrefix = null;
    String subParaPrefix = null;


    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        String item = inputArray[i].split(" ")[0];
        if(isPara(item))
        {
            result.append(String.format(PARA_STRING, item, inputArray[i]));
            result.append("\t");
            result.append("\n");
            paraPrefix = item;
        }
        else if(isSubPara(item))
        {
            result.append(String.format(SUBPARA_STRING, paraPrefix, item, inputArray[i]));
            result.append("\t");
            result.append("\n");
            subParaPrefix = item;
        }
        else if(isClause(item))
        {
            result.append(String.format(CLAUSE_STRING, paraPrefix, subParaPrefix, item, inputArray[i]));
            result.append("\t\t");
            result.append("\n");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}

public static boolean isPara(String source)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\([A-Z]\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    boolean b = m.matches();

    return b;
}

public static boolean isSubPara(String source)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\([[0-9]|i]+\\)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    boolean b = m.matches();

    return b;
}

public static boolean isClause(String source)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\([a-z]\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    boolean b = m.matches();

    return b;
}}
```